# $$hashKey for object in angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am new in angular2 and wondering if there is any alternative to `$$hashKey` in angular2.

I used `$$hashKey` in angularjs for identifying objects.

for ex.

```
var arrayItem = {};
for (var key in arrayInstance[0]) {
    if (arrayInstance[0].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       console.log('Key ' + key);
       if (key != '$$hashKey') {
           arrayItem[key] = angular.copy(arrayInstance[0][key]);
       }
    }
}
arrayInstance.push(arrayItem);
```

so I want to alternative for this in angular2.

any inputs?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the deep dive about that subject [Understanding "Object Identity" With ngFor Loops In Angular 2](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/3020-understanding-object-identity-with-ngfor-loops-in-angular-2-beta-3.htm).